# Command button on every row that appears when a cell value meets criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Im somewhat of a noob but learning from a lot of your trials and tribulations on here, this site is invaluable.

Ive finally worked up the courage to ask my first question as Ive trawled this site and google and cant find quite the right solution or one that I can understand lol!

I have a sheet named bookings in that sheet in column F i need a button on every row that appears or is replaced with text depending on the value in cell E of that row. The value to go in cell E that should trigger the button to appear if it matches a value in a cell in range C11:C28 on a sheet named pricing, alternatively the value will match a cell value in range C3:C10 and if this is the case I want the button to be replaced with the text `TPIC`.

If the button is triggered to appear it should copy a range of cells in that row, b3 to d3 and paste it on the next new row available on another sheet named contractor bookings.

Once the button has been clicked and the process executed I would like the button to then change to text reading "contractor" signifying the completion.

I had found this:

```
Sub ContractorService()
Range("B3:E3").Copy
Sheets("ContractorBookings").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

which works great for the button to copy and past where I want, I was unable yo find any guidance etc to take it further to where I need and now here I am.

Would be really great to finally finish this project your help and this community is much appreciated.

Comment: record yourself adding a button on the sheet, then inspect that code.  Then you'll need the `.top` and `.left` properties of the cell to align the button.

Comment: Any other help with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this with a very simple solution that required no VBA code at all which is actually preferred for me. So actually no button! Instead I created a new row in my data sheet with a filter term ie OPEN / CLOSED I needed a hidden row in my sheet to help pull the  data filtered by the term put into "cell A1", in this case OPEN.

Below is an example I used A1 and sheet1 terms to help you follow what I've done, Sheet1 is where your raw data is and sheet2 is where you are filtering and pulling, the example assumes you want to filter by a term in sheet1 row A1, A2 and so on, test, use and adapt at will!

In your sheet2 in cell A1 replicate your filter term that is found in sheet1 row A, below this paste =IF(Sheet1!A1=$A$1,ROW(),"") I then put =IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNT($A:$A),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,SMALL($A:$‌​A,ROWS($1:1))))

Thats it, simples! Works Like a charm, is auto updating and constant no need to click buttons and all the risks of VBS when others save!!! I hope you find this useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you dont realise it but you're asking many questions here and SO is basically a one question per post site :) So, I suggest you get one thing working, then ask more questions. To address your first point of putting a button on each row:

It's certainly possible but quite tricky depending on the height of the rows since there is no real realtionship between rows and shapes (buttons). It can be done but involves a mathmatical relationship between the row height (row.Height) and the button position (button.Top), something which would take too long to explan here. Instead I'd suggest using hyperlinks instead of buttons as they can be put in specific cells / rows. You can read how to do that [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Here is the example code in case the link goes dead:

```
With Worksheets(1) 
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _ 
 Address:="http://example.microsoft.com", _ 
 ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _ 
 TextToDisplay:="Microsoft" 
End With
```

After you've got the hang on that come back and ask your other questions ;)

Comment: I didn't realise, no, but after spending some weeks on the site now a common thing I noticed was when people ask for help as on obvious stage of a larger change, they are always bashed for not giving the complete picture! I suppose its a cant win either way thing ;) thanks for you help though, Ill look into that and get back!

Comment: is there no way to achieve what I want without using vba?